# finding files in unix based on creation/modification date

Tags: unix

How to find files on a unix server which were created/modified in previous month?

for ex. If the current month is Jul then the list of files which were created/modified in Jun should get displayed.

Comment: No common file system records the creation date of a file.  You have access to last modification time, last access time, and last change time (last time metadata for the file changed.)

Comment: I would use `find` and look at the `-amin -anewer -atime -cmin -cnewer -ctime -mmin -mtime` options for possible options.    And see Williams comment about the creation time not being persisted.

Comment: Linux ext4 records creation date, and FreeBSD's native filesystem does too. They're not easy to get at though, since most tools and scripting languages don't know about them.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to execute that command.

- `ls -laR | grep monthName` where `montName` could be Jan,Feb,Mar, and so on ... (remember to change working directory to directory that you're interested in. Also notice that this method is recursive so all sub-directories will be inspected

With this you also retrieve all file permission and so on...

I'm sure that will be better ways (if them jump into my mind, I'll edit this post) but since I'm in coffee break, this is the faster that I find.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find files modified in the previous month, you will need to use `find` with a set range, for example:

```
cd /  (if you are wanting to start from the root)
find . -type f -mtime +26d -mtime -56d -print
```

You should adjust your range to include the dates that you wish to include.

All the best to you!

Answer (score 2):

```
monthToFind=`date -d "1 months ago" "+%Y-%m"`
find . -printf "%TY-%Tm %p\n" | egrep "^$monthToFind " | sed "s/^$monthToFind //g"
```

This will be slower than using a time range in find. But the time range is hard to determine, and quickly becomes invalid, possibly even while the command is executing.

Unfortunately this will miss files modified last month when they were also modified this month. I don't know of a way to determine these files.